# setScriptPath in Zend can't find file

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am working through a Zend framework book and is stuck for days on the example where I change the default view location. The method is as listed:

```
$this->view->setScriptPath("/views/");
$this->render("news");
```

I place my `news.phtml` file in the `views` directory(rather than the default `views/scripts/artist` but all I got was a message that says the page is not found. I have tried many methods from the web, such as typing

```
$this->view->setScriptPath("/application/views/");
```

or

```
$this->view->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH."/views/");
```

but all are not working.

Can someone please enlighten me?

---

To improve the clarity, I kind of suspect it got to do with my machine setup. I am running on Mac 10.7 and I have activated the built-in PHP and Apache. Since Zend provides it's own stack, will there be any clash in the setting files such as php.ini?

---

More edits:
I am putting down the whole method:

```
public function newsAction()
{
    //Check if the user is logged in

    //Get the user's id
    //
    //Get the artists
    $artists = array("Thievery Corporation",
        "The Eagles",
        "Elton John");

    //Set the view vairables
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setRender('news');
    $this->view->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/views/');
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNeverController(true)->setRender('news');
}
```

I placed the `news.phtml` in the `views` directory. The URL I type is `http://localhost:10088/loudbite/artist/news`. The `artistController` is in the controllers folder. Still doesn't work.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `setScriptPath()` or `addScriptPath`, you need to specify the absolute path to the directory, or a path relative to your current directory.  For portability, using an absolute path is best.

When calling `Zend_View::render()` you must pass the script name including its extension.

Based on your last example, try something like this:

```
$view->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/');
$html = $view->render('news.phtml');
```

Just make sure to get the path correct.  My example assumes you have `views` in your `application` folder.

EDIT:
***If you are in a controller and you want to use a different view script***, use the [View Renderer helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.viewrenderer) instead:

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setRender('news');
```

This tells the view renderer to look for a view script `news.phtml` instead of the name of your action.  However, it still looks in `views/scripts/controller/` for news.phtml.  Therefore you need the following changes as well:

```
// set view script path to the base of the views folder
$this->view->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/');

$this->_helper
     ->viewRenderer
     ->setNeverController(true) // do not render into controller subdirectories
     ->setRender('news');       // set render script to news.phtml
```

When you are using Zend Application, it does its own view rendering, so unless you are trying to render html for use directly, you shouldn't use Zend_View yourself.  After your controller action method completes, Zend Application is going to automatically render a view script and attempt to output it, along with any layout to the browser.  If you did create your own Zend_View, you would need to terminate the request before the action finishes, as not to render any other content.  There are also ways to disable the layout or view rendering as an alternative.

Comment: I tried that before. One of the countless permutations that I tried. I doesn't work.

Comment: Do you get an exception in most cases and not in some?  I used my exact method above both in Zend application and standalone so you should be able to get it working.  From where are you trying to do this? A controller or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. The code above is in the controller, so the view will be directed to the default views/scripts/ folder. If I change to another folder via setScriptPath(),my browser will say page not found.

Comment: There is a better way to switch view scripts from within a controller. Check back in a few minutes, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure its your PHP/Apache configuration per-se, but there is definitely something that isn't right.  The same code I gave you I tested and it works.  Technically, since your action name is news, you don't need the setRender, only the setNeverController and setScriptPath.  I'm tempted to see your directory structure in case that's the issue, but I think you have it right.  If you are getting an error that your errorcontroller or error.phtml wasn't found, you can edit your ErrorController.php to `var_dump($errors->exception->getTraceAsString());` and exit before it tries to render.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. The file exists and permissions are fine, just for this specific module controller views are not working. very strange.

Comment: I've even done a dump of the view renderer to see what is going on and  everything looks like the way it should be.

Comment: @Adgezaza you may want to create a new question with as many details as you can.  I don't know what the solution is based on your comments.

Comment: @drew010 I decided to do something else which turned out to be a better solution. I was having the problem when setting my viewRender Helper to render an alternative script. This was for if error's occurred in a tab I would open for an oauth authorization request. For now I am doing the whole process in the same browser tab and redirecting back to my application upon success.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Zend_Application? Or are you just trying to use Zend_View independently?

The code you have creates a Zend_View object and assigns it to $view, but then you call setScriptPath on $this->view, not the Zend_View you just created.

If you are using Zend_Application, you can set your script path in application.ini

```
// Layout
resources.layout.layout = "layout"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"

// Views
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
resources.view.basePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/"
```

Comment: Adding the Zend_View object was from some forum postings I read. It doesn't work even if I remove that statement.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Mistake on my part, but I didn't know it was important.
When loading the project in Netbeans for the first time, it requested for the index file, which is `index.php` in the `public` folder. I left it empty. It should be clearly defined during the project creation in Netbeans.
If you already committed the mistake, then you may go to the index.php to amend the definitions.